# How to update the value of a column after Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have following table and when I run the following query , `select * from mytable` , I get following result.

```
Column 1                      Value 1
--------------------------------------
Row 1                        1
Row 2                        0
Row 3                        1
Row 4                        0
Row 5                        1
Row 6                        0
```

But I need all the values to 0, no matter if it's 1 or 0. So the representation would be something like this.

```
Column 1                      Value 1
--------------------------------------
Row 1                        0
Row 2                        0
Row 3                        0
Row 4                        0
Row 5                        0
Row 6                        0
```

I can create a table variable and then go ahead and updte the records after inserting to it, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

```
select Column1, '0' as  Value1  from mytable
```

Comment: or `select [Column 1], 0 as [Value 1] from mytable` if he wants the space in the names of the columns

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE mytable SET [Value 1] = 0
```

Will change the value for all rows. But I have a feeling there is more to your question. Can you explain *why* you need the `Value 1` field changed *after* the `SELECT`?

If you want all the `Column 1` rows with a zero for `Value 1`, change your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT Column1, '0' [Value 1] FROM mytable
```

Comment: I am exporting the value to XML and while exporting I need to set it to 0 , irespective of the value in DB

Comment: @Simsons - Then just change the `SELECT` to use `0` for `[Value 1]`

Comment: If I have 10 columns , Do I have to write all the 10 cl names just to set '0' [Valu1], 
For example Slect col1,col2.col3,'0' col4,col5,col6,col7,col8 ,col9,col10 fro, table

Comment: Yes, you can replace any field in your select with a fixed value. In fact, you can include values that are not even fields in you table if you want. Just use the format `[value] as [field_name]`